# flutter url_launcher package is not working for iOS devices

Tags: flutter, dart, url-launcher

I'm using flutter `url_launcher: ^6.0.20` for my project. but it's not working for iOS devices but it's working for the android devices without any problem.

```
Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
       children: [
        GestureDetector(
        onTap: () async {
        final contact = contactNumber;
        await launch('tel:$contact');
                               
       },
       child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
               const Text(
                'Hotline - ',
                style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 25.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                       
                ),
              ),
             Text(
              contactNumber,
              style: const TextStyle(
                     fontSize: 25.0,
                     fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                     decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
                     ),
                   ],
                 ),
              ),
```

`contactNumber` is coming form the backend api. and I've assigned that value to contactNumber variable.

here is the package below,

https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher

**It's working properly for android. not working for the iOS. there is no error on the code. Is the problem in the package.?**

Comment: try the steps given here https://pub.dev/documentation/url_launcher/latest/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a method for make a call.

```
 Future<void> _makePhoneCall(String phoneNumber) async {
  final Uri launchUri = Uri(
  scheme: 'tel',
  path: phoneNumber,
  );
await launchUrl(launchUri);
 }
```

then call on onPressed:

```
_makePhoneCall("01*********");
```

> don't forget to add permission on info.plist.
>
> if you add dependency on runtime, it may be not working. So stop the
> run and build the project again

Answer (score 0):

try it, it was worked for me `launch("tel://1234567890");`

Comment: I already tried it. but it's not working for iOS.

Comment: Can you send the value to the contact variable?

Comment: @SasithaDilshan If you are testing on an emulator, can you test on a real device if possible? sometimes it happens because of the emulator

Comment: I tested it on real device and emulator both